# Heap dump on Out of Memory error

Tags: java, tomcat6

I am using Tomcat server and I want to get a heap dump on Out of Memory error.
How can I do this by specifying parameters in the Catalina.bat file?
Also is there a way to specify the path where the dump file is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html
you can use option `-XX:HeapDumpPath=./java_pid<pid>.hprof`.

You do not have to modify calatalina.bat or other scripts to add options to Tomcat. Just set system variable `CATALINA_OPTS` before running Tomcat.

Comment: The recommended way to modify CATALINA_OPTS is using the setenv.sh script

Comment: -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError